# Add a column at the begining of datatable

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

Hi everyone I'm sending my row data to my datatable ( plugin for html table display ) through Json I want my table to have a first column always with a checkbox and the following columns are the data from Jsonresponse is there any way to make my datatable to have this property or I have one solution I can convert my Json response ( has row data's ) to have one more field but how can I add this new field to the Jsonresponse .
Thanks in advance would be a great help .

Comment: What code do you have so far? Can you create a JSFiddle (or similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how it'll work on very large tables, But you could try something like this :

```
$(table_selector thead tr).prepend(TH_WITH_HEADER);
$(table_selector tr).prepend(TD_WITH_CHECKBOX_IN_IT);
```

I didn't really try it to see if it works, But I guess it should.

**EDIT**
html :

```
<table class="foo">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>temp</td>
  <td>temp</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var input = $('<td><input type="checkbox" class="bar"></td>');

$('.foo tr').prepend(input);
$('.foo thead tr').prepend('<th>checkbox header</th>');
```

Comment: can you please give an example . what does TD_WITH_CHECKBOX_IN_IT actually mean? I'm sorry if its a stupid question i'm a newbie to jquery .

Comment: Thanks a lot the logic seems to be too good .. but not sure if this works in my senario where I'm populating my table from JSON directly using aoData attribute of Datatables .